# javascript find value from array based on associative array key value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an associative array:

```
var array1 = {
    a1: {
        id: "box1",
        title: "box 1"
    },
    a2: {
        id: "box2",
        title: "box 2"
    },
    a3: {
        id: "box3",
        title: "box 3"
    }
};
```

I then have another array which has references to the first array:

```
var array_order = ["a3:positionA", "a2:postitionB", "a1:positionC"];
```

I want to loop through the first list and then use the second list to find the position text

I am using jQuery so I have

```
$.each(array1, function(i,o) {
  something in here where I can use i to find out what position. e.g. if a1 I would get positionC
}
```

Comment: Possibly irrelevant side note: your `array1` variable is not an array. JavaScript only has one kind of arrays: good old zero-based numeric arrays such as `array_order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier and faster iterate over `array_order` instead of `array1`:

```
for( var i = 0, len = array_order.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var ref = array_order[i].split(':');

    if( ref.length === 2 && ({}).hasOwnProperty.call( array1, ref[0] ) ) {
        var array1Property = array1[ ref[0] ];
        var array1PropertyPosition = ref[1];
    }
}
```

Iteration over `array1` properties can be realized also, but it's significantly slower:

```
for( var prop in array1 )
    if( ({}).hasOwnProperty.call( array1, prop ) )
        for( var i = 0, len = array_order.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            var ref = array_order[i].split(':');
            if( ref.length === 2 && prop === ref[1] ) {
                var array1Property = array1[ prop ];
                var array1PropertyPosition = ref[1];
            }
        }
```

And there is no need in jQuery.

Comment: I ended up iterating over array_order like you said

Comment: Is there any need to double "=" in   ref.length = 2  ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok first things first JS calls associative arrays as objects only.

next to iterate over each key in object

```
for(var prop in array1) {
    if(array1.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        for(key in array_order){
           if( key === prop){
           doSomethingwith(array_order[key]);

           }

        }
}
```

Comment: Iteration over `Array` using `for( in )` are too slow. Try to launch following example in the firebug: https://gist.github.com/978743

Comment: Correction: `for( in )` slower versus `for( var .. ++ )`, except v8, there `for( in )` faster due optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp_array_order = {};
$.each(array_order, function(key, val) { 
    temp_array_order[val.substr(0,2)] = val.substr(3); 
};
$.each(array1, function(key, val) {
    var category = temp_array_order[key];
    ...
});
```

Comment: jQuery `.each` too slow versus simple `for` iteration over array, and your solution are suppose, that `array1` properties names length equals 2 chars always.

Comment: `var category = temp_array_order[key];` there is must be check, that it's `temp_array_order` own property, not one, which coming from prototypes chain.

Comment: @PhillipKovalev meh. The code is smaller. Prototype checking isnt really needed, `$.each` uses a `for` loop internally.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong about jQuery `.each` perfomance -- it's best of all. But I disagree with needless of property ownership checking.

Comment: @Phillip but it's not needed because `$.each` uses `for (var i = 0; ... i++)` It does not use `for ... in` loop.

Comment: I'm telling about iteration over object properties: `$.each(array1, function(key, val) {`, not over array. Look at the source: [core.js#597](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L597)

Comment: @Phillip of your right. Still not needed. Don't need to defend againts extending `Object.prototype` because jQuery dies if you do that.

Comment: I think it's particular solution, which can be applied to `Object` successors only.